# Can an a.s. (almost surely) finite random variable be a.s. UNbounded?

Tags: probability, random-variable

I thought that if a random variable, $\eta^2$,  is assumed to be a.s. finite, then $\eta^2$ must be a.s. bounded. In the Martingale Central Limit Theorem in Hall & Heyde, they assume this: "let $\eta^2$ be an a.s. finite random variable."

In the proof, they have two cases:

Case 1: "Suppose that $\eta^2$ is a.s. bounded so that for some $C (>1)$, $P(\eta^2 < C) = 1$."

Case 2: "Remove the boundedness condition of case 1. Suppose $\eta^2$ is not a.s. bounded. Then given $\epsilon > 0$, chose a continuity point $C$ of $\eta^2$ such that $P(\eta^2 > C) > \epsilon$."

I'm confused as to why $\eta^2$ can be a.s. unbounded when $\eta^2$ is assumed to be an a.s. *finite* random variable.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

not a.s. bounded $\ne$ a.s. unbounded

Standard normal distribution is *not* a.s. bounded. Because there is no value $C$ such that $\mathrm{P}(|Z| < C) = 1$. This does *not* mean Normal distribution is *a.s. unbounded*. It just means that for any arbitrary value $C$, no matter how large, there is non-zero probability that $Z$ exceeds $C$ in absolute value.

Comment: You're right. Also, how do you write in mathematical language that a random variable $X$ is a.s. finite? P($X$ is finite) = 1? If so, is P($Z$ is finite) = 1? How to show it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @flohFasaurus: $P(X<\infty)=1$.